# RX java run 2 http command synchronously and non blocking

Tags: rx-java2

I want to create an observables that will:

1. Fetch data from the server
2. Using the result it got - fetch more data
3. Invoke some callback with the 2nd result.

Nothing is returned eventually, but all this should not block the current thread.

This is what I got:

```
Observable.just(service1.getres1)  // Returns real object
    .flatMap(result1 -> {
            result2 = service2.getRes2(result1));
            return Observable.just(result2);
    })
    .subscribe(gameMiniProfile -> {
               doLogic();
    });
```

This code works, but I think it blocks the thread, I added Thread sleep in one of the callbacks, and a log print after the subscribe and saw that the the thread was blocked.

How can I do that?

Comment: Which thread does it block?

Comment: The calling main thread. I added print at the add - and it just waited for the subscribe to end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that you have structured the observer chain using a `Observable.just()` means that it will run on the same thread as it is subscribed on. None of the operators you used in your code "run on a particular scheduler", according to the documentation.

You can add a `subscribeOn()` operator to have the observer chain run on another scheduler, or use `observeOn()` so that the observers will operate on a different scheduler.

Comment: Can you post an example?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to specify the `Scheduler` on which an `Observable` will operate, using the operator `subscribeOn`.

But much more important, since you said that you want get data from the server (so it makes more sense to be async), you should model your services so that they can return an `Observable`. The signatures should be something like these:

```
Observable<YourResltObj1> getres1(); // service1

Observable<YourResltObj2> getRes2(YourResltObj1 result); // service2
```

So now, you can simple do:

```
service1.getres1()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .flatMap(result -> service2.getRes2(result))
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // if you want your doLogic() to be executed on the UI thread
    .subscribe(gameMiniProfile -> {
               doLogic();
    });
```